# Unable to call firebase cloud function from xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a firebase cloud function from my app. I'm using xamarin android. I'm trying to call it with:

```
public Task<string> AddPoint()
    {
        FirebaseFunctions firebaseFunctions = 
        FirebaseFunctions.GetInstance(app));

        var func = firebaseFunctions.GetHttpsCallable("addPoint").Call(someData);

        return func.Result.Cast<Task<string>>();
    }
```

But firebase console dosen't register that the function was called. The return func.Result.Cast>() throws an error: "Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete." Adding a breakpoint, it says the same in Result property. func properties (IsCanceled, Iscompleted and IsSuccessful) are always false.
I followed the samples code in https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable, but it dosen't include a c# sample.

Comment: Please add a breakpoint in the return `func.Result.Cast<Task<string>>();` What is the return value you get? And Cloud Functions is available in the following regions:

us-central1 (Iowa)
us-east1 (South Carolina)
us-east4 (Northern Virginia)
europe-west1 (Belgium)
europe-west2 (London)
asia-east2 (Hong Kong)
asia-northeast1 (Tokyo)  please check this thread:https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations, please make sure you have in these regions.

Comment: The return func.Result.Cast<Task<string>>() throws an error: "Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete." Adding a breakpoint, it says the same in Result property. func properties (IsCanceled, Iscompleted and IsSuccessful) are always false. My function is set to us-central1 in firebase console and I believe it is the default setting when not specified in code. Cast<>, by the way, is an extension method to cast java objects into .net ones.

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out. First it's necessary to implement IContinuation and IOnSuccessListener interface:

```
public class Continuation : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Gms.Tasks.IContinuation
    {
        public Java.Lang.Object Then(Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
        {           
            return task.Result;
        }
    }

public class TaskSuccessListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnSuccessListener
{
    public event EventHandler<OnSuccessEventArgs> Success;

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        Success?.Invoke(this, new OnSuccessEventArgs { Result = result });
    }

    public class OnSuccessEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Java.Lang.Object Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The response of a callable cloud function come as Java.Lang.Object that can be cast into a HashMap. 
However func is a java task and it won't block the .Net task thread. So it was necessary to manually pause the thread using a TaskCompletionSource.
IOnSuccessListener will be called when the cloud function return successfuly. Then TaskCompletionSource can be set to continue the Task.
It can be used like so:

```
public class FirebaseFunction : AppCompatActivity
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> isRunning;
    TaskSuccessListener.Success += TaskSuccessListener_Success;

    public async Task<string> AddPoint()
    {
        FirebaseFunctions firebaseFunctions = 
        FirebaseFunctions.GetInstance(FirebaseApp));

        var func = firebaseFunctions.GetHttpsCallable("function")
       .Call(someData)
       .ContinueWith(new Continuation())
       .AddOnSuccessListener(this, taskCompletionListener);

        await isRunning.Task;

        HttpsCallableResult httpsResult = (HttpsCallableResult)func.Result;
        HashMap map = httpsResult.Data.JavaCast<HashMap>();

        if (map.ContainsKey("data"))
        {
            response = map.Get("data").ToString();
        }
        return response;
    }

    private void TaskSuccessListener_Success(object sender, TaskSuccessListener.OnSuccessEventArgs e)
    {
        //Alternatively it is possible to get the result directely from e.result         
        //HttpsCallableResult httpsResult = (HttpsCallableResult)e.Result;
        //HashMap map = httpsResult.Data.JavaCast<HashMap>();
        isRunning.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution, based on yours that is working for me and looks simpler:

```
        var func =  FirebaseFunctions.Instance.GetHttpsCallable("sayHello").Call();
        await func;
        HttpsCallableResult httpsResult = (HttpsCallableResult)func.Result;
```

Comment: I remember that, at the time, I've tried the way you're suggesting, but the await func part simply woundn't wait for the task to finish. Instead it just execute immediately causing func.Result to be null. Thus the use of TaskCompletionSource to manually stop the thread.